# Running .exe without copying .dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, exe

I have Visual Studio 2015 solution ready for delivery. I have a requirement that the .exe should run out of the box. However, I am getting "missing dll..." errors. Is there any way I could make it possible for someone to run the exe without him needing to download bunch of ddls? Can I build the .exe to be executable as stand-alone somehow?

Comment: Err, ship the DLLs with the product?

Comment: Yes, but if the person does not have redist package, does that mean he should install it first? Am I the one to blame then? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to statically link the binary. In the project settings (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation), use /MT, /MTd for the Release, Debug configurations respectively. However, this bloats the size of the executable.

[MSDN documentation on /MT, /MTd options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)

Comment: Works as a charm. Thanks!