# How to statically link visual studio (windows) libraries into exe file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I know how to statically link libraries I have produce in my solution. Hoewever when I try the exe file on a machine that has not visual studio 2012 I got an error that the exe file is looking for msvd110.dll in order to execute. There are some other dlls that are missing so I would like to know how can I create the exe file with all needed libraries linked statically?

I colleague told me to change the setting "Use of MFC" from "Use Standard windows libraries" to "Use MFC in a Static Library" however I think that's not the way to go since we are not using any of the MFC functions in our project (are we?).

Any advise?

Comment: Under C++/Code Generation, you need to change the Runtime Library setting to `Multi-threaded` from `Multi-threaded DLL`, or `Multi-threaded Debug` instead of `Multi-threaded Debug DLL`. Note that this setting should match in all the libraries you're linking, too.

Comment: And that will make a 100% independent machine exe file? Let me try it.

Comment: [Check this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928449/running-exe-without-copying-dlls).

Comment: So just to be sure, the "Use of MFC" has nothing to do with it, right?